# A table of plots of different functions

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction, list-manipulation

I want to create a `Table` of individual `Plot`s where the table's index-variable is a series of functions. For example:

Take two simple functions, `f[x_] := 1/x` and `f[x_] := x^2`. I want to create a `Table` containing a `Plot` of each of them - i.e., I want a table that contains

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

for each of `f[x_] := 1/x` and `f[x_] := x^2`.

In this simple case, the result would look the same as

```
{Plot[1/x, {x, 1, 10}], Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}]}
```

However, I want to be able to do this for more than two functions and with maximum economy - so, without the repetition implied in the above 2-function list.

I tried

```
Table[Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}], {f[x], {1/x, x^2}}]
```

and

```
Table[Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}], {f, {1/x, x^2}}]
```

but they produce blank plots.

How do I do it?

Comment: You could `Map` a pure function, e.g., `Plot[#, {x, 1, 10}] & /@ {1/x, x^2}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Table[Plot[f, {x, 1, 10}], {f, {1/x, x^2}}]
Table[Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}], {f, {1/# &, #^2 &}}]
Table[Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}], {f, {1/x &, x^2 &}}]
```

all give

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The working examples are all using the pattern iterating over a given list from the section Scope on the documentation page for Table.

```
Table[Sqrt[x], {x, {1, 4, 9, 16}}]
```

(*{1, 2, 3, 4}*)

Plot prefers the pure function as input.

In the section Generalizations & Extensions

```
Table[a[x]!, {a[x], 6}]
```

(*{1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720}*)

The variables need not just be symbols!

This is continued in the section Applications where parameters are given to the listed function.

Nice is:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}]], {x, 0, 15}]
```

instead of

```
    Plot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}], {x, 0, 15}]
```

The `Evaluate` is needed to force evaluation of the `Table` before it is fed to `Plot`!

This cases all make use of the 5th definition of Table:
Table[expr,{i,{Subscript[i, 1],Subscript[i, 2],[Ellipsis]}}]
uses the successive values Subscript[i, 1], Subscript[i, 2], [Ellipsis].

[image: definition]

This is best illustrated in the section Relations to other functions.

Table can substitute successive elements in a list into an expression!
All that is required is a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html)  and a iterator like x or f as Symbol.

More insight in the nonworking example can be gained if the Plot is not used:

```
Table[f[x], {f, {1/x, x^2}}]
```

(*{(1/x)[x], (x^2)[x]}*)

[Have a nice day.](http://%3Cimg%20src=%22http://vg09.met.vgwort.de/na/86f3b2707f51483da5f42ee13f5561c3%22%20width=%221%22%20height=%221%22%20alt=%22%3E)